# Positional argument after asterisk in Python

Tags: python, django

I have model in Django. `Project`. It has foreign key to `Organization` model with `related_name='projects'`. So I can call `my_org.projects.all()`. But what if i'd like to call `my_org.projects()`? Let's check:

```py
(Pdb++) org = Organization.objects.first()
(Pdb++) org.projects()
*** TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'
(Pdb++) org.projects(None)
*** TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

That's really uncommon. So what causes this?
Here's the code located in `RelatedManager` in Django:

```py
        def __call__(self, *, manager):
            manager = getattr(self.model, manager)
            manager_class = create_reverse_many_to_one_manager(manager.__class__, rel)
            return manager_class(self.instance)
```

Can someone explain me how is this method constructed? As far as I know you can't place positional argument after an asterisk `*args`. But here we have `(self, *, manager)`. Looks like programmer won't be able to pass `manager` ever!

Comment: Did you tried `org.projects(manager=your_manager)`?

Comment: It is a keyword-only required argument. You have to call the function with the keyword= `org.projects(manager=None)` See here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about specifying keyword argument without default value.

Answer (score 0):

As @Abdul Niyas P M and @N Chauhan commented this is a trick to force calling this function using keyword arguments. Every positional argument will be consumed by asterisk, so the only way to pass `manager` is by using keyword-argument and will look like `org.projects(manager=None)`. It's also nicely explained [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/usage-asterisks-python#KOAWOPA).